# Cannot connect to port 3306

Tags: iptables, firewall

I'm running CentOS on my VPS and are trying to get remote access to my MySQL database. So I added a line to my iptables using this command:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

But I can't get access to my mysql database. When I do a port scan with nmap This is the result:

```
>nmap -p 3306 x.x.x.x
>3306/tcp filtered mysql
```

So stat is not `OPEN`. This are all the input rules on the VPS. There is one line (already in there) that holds `REJECT`. Is that blocking the traffic to port 3306?

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:imap
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:EtherNet/IP-1
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpts:35000:35999
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
```

Thanks in advance!

my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
bind-address=x.x.x.x

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I looked at your iptables output more thoroughly and notice that you have some issues there.

```
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql
```

You are rejecting all traffic before your rule explicitly allowing traffic to MySQL has a chance to be matched. You need to reorder those rules.

---

Old Answer:

It is likely that your MySQL server isn't actively listening for remote connections.

The command 'ss -ln | grep 3306' probably won't return any results.

Check your MySQL configuration file for the keywords skip-networking and bind-address. If skip-networking is present in the configuration, comment it out or remove it. Ensure bind-address is set to either 0.0.0.0 ('wildcard') or a system IP address. Restart MySQL to apply the configuration changes.

You will want to ensure you do not have any accounts that are accessible to the world with empty or trivial passwords. Restricting remote access to the MySQL port is strongly recommended in addition to MySQL user and database ACLs.

Comment: Where should I type that?

Comment: `ss -ln | grep 3306` returns: `0  50  x.x.x.x:3306 *:*`

Comment: I added my.cnf file. Don't think something's wrong with that. Also restarted mysql.

Comment: @Timo002 I looked over your iptables rules more thoroughly and updated  my answer.

Comment: I see the issue. Now I need to find out how to reorder or delete the last to lines and add a new one on top

Comment: YES I solved the problem! I deleted the last 2 rules and added one on top of the list! Now it is open and I can connect to the mysql DB remotely! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

*This should be a comment not an anwer, i don't have enough rep.*

Since the

> 3306/tcp **filtered** mysql

You have probably something wrong with your firewall. If mysql isn't accepting connections to 3306 due not binding to the network it should be **closed**

**tcpdump** is your friend to debug the issue, try to check if packets are actually arriving

Just to point that filtered state is often associated with firewall issues, and closed with the actual service not binding

Answer (score 0):

The rules in a netfilter firewall are checked sequentially until the first match.

The -A switch to iptables adds new rules  at the *end* of your existing configuration.

Your existing configuration opens a number of ports and ends with a rule that matches and REJECTs everything that wasn't opened up previously. Then you added  the MySQL port after that.

That rule will never be reached and the MySQL port remains closed.

You should have used the -I switch to iptables to insert the new rule at the beginning of your firewall config.